# How to give class to last child of a div in jquery with onchange function

Tags: jquery, html, css

M using a form in which m changing the value of a div based on dropdown list.as i want to show data of div on onchange event of dropdown list..but only once..(thats second problem)..as far as i have gone is to use append and .last or :last-child but stil i m only able to show the value out of my form's div..but i want before submit..so what should i do..plz help..as i did hard try..and should i choose second last div of my form..is it possible??

sorry if i  ask question in wrong way and be sure as i am not asking to select last element in jquery so before saying duplicate question..plz take time and read my qustion..thanx..

here is my code..

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function (){
    $('#wpbs-field-4').change(function(){
    $a=$( "#wpbs-field-4" ).val();
    if($a == 'Yes')
    {
    $( ".wpbs-form-item").last().append( "<div>Cost of Package is :- 10,000 Rs.</div>" );
    }
    else
    {
    $( ".wpbs-form-item" ).last().append( "<div>Cost of Package :- 5,000 Rs.</div>" );
    }

    });

});
</script>
```

and here is my structure

outer div :- .wpbs-form
for div :- .wpbs-form-form
form field div :- .wpbs-form-form .wpbs-form-item

and sorry but please help me that how can i remove last message if there is already like if on yes there will be message like rs 10000 so if i select no then previous message should be delete and then there will be only 5000..sorry for asking big..but believe me i tried hard..so plz help...

so plz help me..thanx..and plz dnt give negative marks.plz

Comment: plz type complete wrds. thx.

Comment: this thing desperately needed a review

Comment: @ patrick done..and @ daniel din get u??

Comment: @Avinafh. Let me first tell you I didn't give you downvoted; Stack Exchange's help says clearly, downvotes are given if a quality of a question is low. In this manner, your words. Let me tell you, when people gives edits, they must fill in the edit summary, e.g. fixed grammar, improve context, fixed spelling, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, suppose the div is `#theOne` and the children are `li.children`:

### html:

```
<div id="theOne">
    <li class="hisBabies"></li>
    <li class="hisBabies"></li>
    <li class="hisBabies"></li>
    ...
</div>
<style class="changeLastChild">
</style>
```

### js:

```
var executed = false;
$('#wpbs-field-4').change(function(){
    if(!executed) {
        executed = true;
        $("style.changeLastChild").html("#theOne li.hisBabies:last-child {color: red}");
    }
});
```

**How about this?**

For the "remove the message", you must first give it a `id`, in this case: `#info`. If I were you, I would do something like this:

### html:

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

### js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#info").html(""); //a function, first clears the inner html
    if (something) {
        $("#info").html("New message!"); //change the inner html to a message
    }
});
```

You may use a `switch` instead of a `if` statement, if there are a lot of message strings to be changed.

Comment: Hey daniel i din said that you give downvote..and really thanx for your answer but its not working in my case..:(

Comment: and please help me that how can i add class to that div which i added by append funciton..thanx

Comment: how about `$( ".wpbs-form-item" ).last().append( "<div class='myClass'>Cost of Package :- 5,000 Rs.</div>" );`

Comment: WOwww..i tried this but i din use ' ' but now working...really thanx man..:)

Comment: but sorry still i din get what i want..:(